# Email scraper, trigger another message if the expected email didn't come, or was empty

Tags: python, email, gmail

I have a service which sends emails with attached reports per schedule (daily, hourly, 30+ sendings in total in a cron job).

All emails come to a Gmail account inbox which is added to 'cc'.

I wonder if there a simple way to expect an email at some defined time and trigger another email if it didn't come or if it doesn't have an attachment? 
php, python, java solutions will do

Comment: What do you want to do? Read your GMail account with a Python script?

Comment: if there are any gmail API which could wait for an email and trigger an email, that would be great. 
Otherwise yes, I'd like to read my inbox, search for an email (let say by title), and check if it exists and contains an attachment. If no, initiate a notification.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a blog about "How to Read Email From Gmail Using Python": http://codehandbook.org/how-to-read-email-from-gmail-using-python/

Use a cron to read your emails periodically.